# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED using websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, connection-refused

I'm trying to create a websocket without any framework, in vanilla JavaScript.

I'm trying to send a basic text websocket, but it keeps throwing me the error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[Here's the code on repl.it](https://repl.it/@lolfail/websocket-test)

I have a Content Security Policy set:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

my websocket is set to ws://localhost/ at the 9000 port.

Anyway here's my script.js file:

```js
let a = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000");
a.onopen = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    a.send("working?");
  }, 1000);
};
a.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log(event.data);
}
```

and my srv.js (in nodejs) file:

```js
let server = require('ws').Server;
let srv = new server({port: 9000});
srv.on('connection', ws => {
  ws.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(`Received message => ${msg}`)
  })
  ws.send('hey')
})
```

Comment: do you have `srv.on('connection', function connection(ws) { ... })` on the server side?

Comment: Also, sometimes there are issues when using `localhost:9000`, try using an actual ip `127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn changed the question, and I added what you wrote, I added message handler too and I sent a message, writing the ip address instead of localhost made the error disappear, but It can't send the message somehow and it probably isn't even detecting messages anyway thanks

Comment: it can't connect to it, i figured out the ip address with tracert in cmd but it looks like the ip isn't correct

Comment: `CONNECTION_REFUSED` is an error that occurs when the specified port, in this case `9000`, is not opened. Have you properly started a node server that is listening on the specified port? Btw. I have tried your code on my local machine and it works to no surprise.

Comment: @Bajro I chose an open (and allowed) port but it still throws the connection refused error

Comment: @CodeZer0 Are there any updates on this issue? I have changed ports, nmap scanned them and they are open, I've switched through ip to localhost. I have tried to get my friend to connect but it throws the connection refused

Comment: @Sean I answered my post there you might find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that this old question of mine hasn't been answered, after that i dig into websockets and figured out that the problem I think was that I didn't set `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"` in the server
With ws it would be:

```
let server = require('ws').Server;
let srv = new server({port: 9000, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"});
srv.on('connection', ws => {
  ws.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(`Received message => ${msg}`)
  })
  ws.send('hey')
});
```

Although my question is incorrect as ws is an external module that helps with websockets, anybody who thinks that making a websocket server without this module is easy is wrong, it is possible but the amount of code for just a simple server like in my question takes almost 50 lines of code which is not worth it, as ws has many features that makes it easy and more reliable than without using external modules.

For anybody who wants to actually make it for learning purposes [here's the websocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) explained, but since they don't provide code I made a [repl on repl.it](https://repl.it/@lolfail/websocket-server-without-external-modules)

Comment: The servers seems to run fine with this, will have to test later with a friend to see if it's solved the connection problem, however. Seems promising

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ws is an external module".  You mean this is a plugin available somewhere to help with websockets?  If so, where?  Also your repl link is broken.